# I used history.pushState function but when I go back by browser back button my content did not change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used history pushstate function but , when I go back by browser back button, my Url changed, but my content did not change?I do not know how to get content when I clicked back button?

Comment: Guessing you are not listening for onpopstate

Comment: Note that history pushstate *only* changes the URL on the browser.  It's not "browser pushstate" or "page pushstate" - it just changes the URL.  When you go back to that url you need to update/refresh your page so that it matches the state in the url.  More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API